# static IP multicast routing with IPSEC

Tags: ipsec, multicast

for a specific application, I need to route a multicast flow with IPSEC (we use a CISCO ASA 5508 firewall), I am not a network expert then I will try to explain as best as I can our issue
I don't need any IGMP management everything is static:

- on eth_input we receive "multicast" messages (meaning that destination address is in the multicast range ex: 229.0.0.X
- on eth_output we need to forawrd these message in IPSEC message (defined by one IP public address for source and one IP public address for destination. On eth_output we disable IGMP

then basically the need is to forward statically the messages after encapsulation in IPSEC

On my side, I understand that multicast + IPSEC is not trivial, but I don't understand if this due to IGMP management only or not.

then my question:

- is the routing problem due to the fact that our destination is in the multicast range (then root cause there is a limitation in the firewall that reject the routing configuration) ?
- or is the routing problem due only to IGMP management with IPSEC (then in our case we will disable IGMP) ?

thanks very much for help

best regards

Comment: This post seems to lack a question, it's just a problem description. Please be specific in what you're asking.

Comment: thanks for feedback I have tried to clarify the questions

Comment: IPSec does not actually support multicast. The way to do it is to first tunnel in GRE, then tunnel the GRE in IPSec. Cisco has a VTI (Virtual Tunnel Interface) solution to do that. By the way, the `229.0.0.X` range is reserved, and you should not use it. The Organization-Local scope (`239.0.0.0/8`) is available for your use.